# Unzip a zip file in google storage on google cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Here I need help at 2 points: How could I achieve my bucket directory on google cloud shell and how to unzip a zip file in my bucket in google storage again on google cloud shell?

When I try:

```
unzip gs://bucket-name/zip-file-name.zip
```

google cloud shell says: *-bash: gs://bucket-name/: No such file or directory*

but when I write: `gsutil ls gs://bucket-name/`, it lists files in the bucket. So, I decided to first achieve my bucket directory than unzip. At this point, if I write: `gsutil gs://bucket-name/` it says: *CommandException: Invalid command "gs://bucket-name/"*

What should I do to unzip a zip file in google storage on google cloud shell?

Comment: 1) Copy the file from Cloud Storage to the Cloud Shell file system using **gsutil**. 2) Unzip the downloaded file. 3) The program **unzip** does not contain drivers to support the Cloud Storage **gs:** namespace.

Comment: There is a "gsutil cp" command but I guess it is for copy the file from Cloud Storage to the local. How could I copy it to Cloud Shell file system? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Using **gsutil cp gs://bucket/objectname local-filename**.

Comment: It works, thank you. Could you please write it as answer instead of comment? I would like to check it as the answer of this question. In addition to, do you have any idea about unzip a zip file directly in a bucket where a zip file exists instead of in Cloud Shell file system?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to do it in place. What you can do is open a cloud shell (from the >_ button to the right of the search bar) and in the shell that spawns at the bottom you can type:

gsutil cp gs://bucket/objectname local-filename

to move the file to the cloud shell machine.

Then you can unzip it:

gunzip local-file name

and then you copy it back with:

gsutil cp local-filename gs://bucket/objectname